# How to dynamically add columns based on relationship (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have two tables in MySQL which are of the format below:

**TABLE 1**

| P_Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | Y |

**Table 2**

| F_Key | F 1 | F 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 03 |
| A | 02 | 04 |
| B | 01 | 04 |

Now I want to create a join between these two tables, such that the values of the second table are merged to a single row, like in the format below:

| P_Key | Value | 1.F1 | 1.F2 | 2.F1 | 2.F2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 01 | 03 | 02 | 04 |
| B | Y | 01 | 04 | -- | -- |

What is the best method to obtain this kind of structure?

Edit: As per instructions given, I will add some queries, and why they did not work on my use case.

If I did a simple join (let's say INNER JOIN), the resulting structure would be as below:

| P_Key | Value | F_Key | F 1 | F 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | A | 01 | 03 |
| A | X | A | 02 | 04 |
| B | Y | B | 01 | 04 |

Which is not the structure I require.

Also, if the table 2 had another row for Key A and table 2 has following data:

| F_Key | F 1 | F 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 03 |
| A | 02 | 04 |
| A | 05 | 08 |
| B | 01 | 04 |

then the resulting table would be

| P_Key | Value | 1.F1 | 1.F2 | 2.F1 | 2.F2 | 3.F1 | 3.F2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 01 | 03 | 02 | 04 | 05 | 08 |
| B | Y | 01 | 04 | -- | -- | -- | -- |

Comment: The best way to solve this is to do some [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL+join+convert+rows+to+colums), learn from it, and share the SQL statement that you tried. Also explain why it failed or why you think the results are not correct. (Please)

Comment: What should be the result if `Table 2` has more than two rows with F_Key `A`?

Comment: @Luuk Sure, I will add some queries with that regard, but I guess I dont have a good query in that sense

Comment: @BartoszSzymański Ideally, more columns would appear, like 3. F1, 3.F2. 

I know this is not the most optimal data representation, hence the question.

Comment: See either "pivot-table" or `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: I will add some queries..."   Queries are those _things_ that start with `SELECT`, and not some table with info, because normally that is the output of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a SQL query in which more columns "appear" based on the data it reads. The columns of all queries must be fixed at the time you prepare the query.

The type of query you're describing is often called a pivot-table query. Here's an example:

```
SELECT P_Key, MAX(Value) AS Value,
  MAX(CASE rownum WHEN 1 THEN F1 END) AS `1.F1`,
  MAX(CASE rownum WHEN 1 THEN F2 END) AS `1.F2`,
  MAX(CASE rownum WHEN 2 THEN F1 END) AS `2.F1`,
  MAX(CASE rownum WHEN 2 THEN F2 END) AS `2.F2`
FROM (
  SELECT Table1.P_Key, Table1.Value, Table2.F1, Table2.F2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table2.F_Key) AS rownum
  FROM Table1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.P_Key = Table2.F_Key
) AS t
GROUP BY P_Key;
```

(The ROW_NUMBER() window function requires MySQL 8.0.)

If you want more F1/F2 columns, you have to code them explicitly. You may want to first find out the maximum number of rows per F_Key in Table2:

```
SELECT MAX(count) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Table2 GROUP BY F_Key
) AS t;
```

Then write code in your application to build a query with as many pairs of F1/F2 columns as that max count.